# How can I get the arguments for function that I pass as a parameter to another function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access arguments from the function that is being passed as a parameter to make sure to pass those through, however I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

How can I get the arguments for func so that I can pass the message through when calling it?

UPDATE: maybe a better question is why can't I log `func.arguments`?

```js
function a(func){
  console.log(func.arguments)
  return function(){
    func.apply(null, func.arguments);
  }
}

function log(message){
  console.log(message)
}

a(log.bind('hello'))()
```

Comment: This is not possible, I believe.

Comment: The `length` property of a function object will tell you how many parameters that function expects.  I think that's the best you can do.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me - what is your goal for getting the arguments from the passed function?

Comment: If the arguments are bound, why do you need to get them to pass them on? They'll be provided automatically via the bound function. If they're not bound, then there are no arguments to  get.

Comment: @CrazyTrain fair point, I was just trying to see how pass params through to the function being called by another function but I guess the only way is to just bind them?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. You can forward arguments from one function to another, but you need to get those arguments when the outer function is invoked. You can also create partially applied functions. Maybe it will be more clear if you describe the problem being solved.

Comment: @CrazyTrain there isn't a real problem, I was just trying to understand how to do something like this so I made up my own problem above.

Comment: There are no arguments until `func` is called. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but its not pretty. you have to return an object with the parameters you want from the function you are passing

```
function a(func){
    console.log(func.arguments)

    //you dont actually need this since you have already called the function before passing
    //return function(){
    //   func.apply(null, func.arguments);
    //}
}


function log(message){
    console.log(message);
    return {
        arguments : arguments //store the arguments and return them
    }; 
}

//you not actually passing the function here (the way you have it written)
//you are calling it and returning its value
//we return { arguments: arguments } so the "a" function can retrieve its properties.
a(log("hello"));
```

Comment: `this` doesn't always refer to the function.

Comment: How is `func.apply` going to work if `func` is a plain object?

Comment: it wont (added comment to my code). The way he has it written hes attempting to call the function twice. both when it gets passed and then when he calls func.apply. Technically he should just remove the func.apply as its no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do is to intercept a function with a "logging" function.

If so, there is a different approach, using ES6 rest params --

```
let withLog = func => (...args) => { 
    console.log(...args); 
    return func(...args);
};

let add = (x, y) => x + y;

withLog(add)(2, 3); // outputs '2 3', returns 5
```